# Do Loop handling Queue Events displaying multiple host output from one event powershell

Tags: powershell, event-handling, filesystemwatcher

I have a script that monitors a directory for csv file changes and displays the results on the screen as an output.  But when a single file has changed i.e. one event multiple lines appear in the write-host output when I only want one.  How do I resolve this?  I have tried adding sleep timers in milliseconds and queue handling to no avail.  Any help greatly appreciated.

This is the code:

```
Clear-Host
$queue = [System.Collections.Queue]::Synchronized((New-Object System.Collections.Queue))
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "C:\test"
$watcher.Filter = "*.csv"
$watcher.NotifyFilter = [System.IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

$srccontents = @()

  $action = { 
    $event = $Event.SourceEventArgs
    $queue.Enqueue($event)
}

  # Register the event handler
  Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
 
Do    
{
    if ($queue.Count -gt 0) 
    {
        $event = $queue.Dequeue()
        $path = $event.FullPath
        $name = $event.Name
        $changeType = $event.ChangeType
        $timeStamp = (Get-ChildItem -Path $path | Select-Object -Property LastWriteTime).LastWriteTime
        $timeStamp = $timeStamp.ToString('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss')
        Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp - Path to file is: $path"    
        Write-Host "Contents of file: "
        $srccontents = Import-Csv -Path $path 
        $srccontents | Select-Object Servername | FT  

    } 
    else 
    {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
    }
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
}while ($true)
```

This is the output, 3 or more when you run more times:

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
23     829609c8-e77...                 NotStarted    False                                 ...                     
The file 'tempcsvfile.csv' was Changed at 09/02/2023 12:31:22 - Path to file is: C:\test\tempcsvfile.csv
Contents of file: 



Servername   
----------   
server1      
server2      
server3      
serversdkjfl4


The file 'tempcsvfile.csv' was Changed at 09/02/2023 12:31:22 - Path to file is: C:\test\tempcsvfile.csv
Contents of file: 

Servername   
----------   
server1      
server2      
server3      
serversdkjfl4


The file 'tempcsvfile.csv' was Changed at 09/02/2023 12:31:22 - Path to file is: C:\test\tempcsvfile.csv
Contents of file: 

Servername   
----------   
server1      
server2      
server3      
serversdkjfl4
```

When I only want 1 result like this:

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
23     829609c8-e77...                 NotStarted    False                                 ...                     
The file 'tempcsvfile.csv' was Changed at 09/02/2023 12:31:22 - Path to file is: C:\test\tempcsvfile.csv
Contents of file: 

Servername   
----------   
server1      
server2      
server3      
serversdkjfl4
```

Comment: What changes are being made to the file? Are you in control of these changes? If so, please share the code or procedure you use

Comment: The only changes is they will be getting is added to from a seperate script using the command:  Add-Content -Path $csvsrvoutput -Value $server
i.e. pcnames in a single column.  
Occasionally a new file will be generated.